# How to test vuex using jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Following is my index.js file from store folder,  I am not done seprate files for action, state and mutations I have done all this in single file of index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
randomMealArray: {},
mealDetails: {},
mealInfo: [],
},

 actions: {
getRandomMeal(context) {
  try {
    axios.get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Set_Meal', response.data)
        let randomMealArray = response.data.meals
        context.commit('Set_Meal', randomMealArray)
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
},
async getMealDetailsById(context, id) {
  try {
    await axios.get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=' + id)
      .then(response => {
        let mealDetails = response.data.meals[0];
        context.commit('setMealDetailsById', mealDetails);
        console.log('mealDetailsfromAPI', mealDetails);

      })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
},
async getSearchResults(context, searchInput) {
  try {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=" + searchInput)
      .then((respose) => {
        let mealInfo = respose.data.meals;
        context.commit('setSearchResults', mealInfo);

      });


  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
},

},
mutations: {
Set_Meal(state, randomMealArray) {
  state.randomMealArray = randomMealArray
},
setMealDetailsById(state, mealDetails) {
  state.mealDetails = mealDetails;

},
setSearchResults(state, payload) {
  state.mealInfo = payload;
}
},
modules: {
}
})
```

please tell me how to test this file using jest. I am trying to test this with some mockResolvedValue but its get error. I am new to vue, vuex and testing also

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide what you've tried so far. Where's your test? What was the result?

Comment: That you don't chain promises makes it barely usable and definitely untestable. Should always be `await axios.get...`. Axios should be mocked in tests, there are many libs and SO topics for that. Then actions can be tested by simply awaiting them and asserting results in state.